# I can't use setState correctly to change value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to use setState to change value in components state (personId), with a value (pid) that I get from inside of render().

There is three scenarios inside of this component. All of those are kind of same scenarios, but with small changes depending on what I receive from API-call with Axios.

I change state inside of componentDidMount, which I guess runs once when the component is opened, I've also tried changing state inside of componentDidUpdate which then causes infinite loop.

I also left out of chunk of code which doesn't really have anything do with this problem just to make it somewhat tidier.

```
class SearchPage extends React.Component {

    state = {
        personId: '',
        person_results: [],
    }

        componentDidMount(){
            //this.props.fetchPersonInfo(this.state.personId)
            let pid;
            if(this.props.results.length > 0){
                if (this.props.results[0].results[0].media_type === 'person'){
                    this.setState({person_results: this.props.results[0].results});
                    pid = this.state.person_results.id;
                } else if (this.props.results[0].results[1].media_type === 'person'){
                    this.setState({person_results: this.props.results[0].results})
                    pid = this.state.person_results.id;
                } else if (this.props.results[0].results[2].media_type === 'person'){
                    this.setState({person_results: this.props.results[0].results})
                    pid = this.state.person_results.id
                }
            }
            this.setState({
                personId: pid,
            })
        }


    render(){
            if (this.props.results.length > 0){
                if (this.props.results[0].results[0].media_type === 'person'){
                    console.log(this.props.results[0].results[0]);
                    console.log(this.state.person_results);
                    return (
                        <div className='.col-md-4 search-container'>
                                <div className='search-results-person'>
                                    <h5 className='search-title'>{this.state.person_results.name}</h5>
                                    <img className='search-image' src={`${img_url}${this.state.person_results.profile_path}`} alt={this.state.person_results.name} />
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                } else if (this.props.results[0].results[1].media_type === 'person'){
                    console.log(this.state.person_results);
                    return (
                        <div className='.col-md-4 search-container'>
                                <div className='search-results-person'>
                                    <h5 className='search-title'>{this.state.person_results.name}</h5>
                                    <img className='search-image' src={`${img_url}${this.state.person_results.profile_path}`} alt={this.state.person_results.name} />
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                } else if (this.props.results[0].results[2].media_type === 'person'){
                    console.log(this.state.person_results);
                    return (
                        <div className='.col-md-4 search-container'>
                                <div className='search-results-person'>
                                    <h5 className='search-title'>{this.state.person_results.name}</h5>
                                    <img className='search-image' src={`${img_url}${this.state.person_results.profile_path}`} alt={this.state.person_results.name} />
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            }
            return (
                <div className='container-fluid'>
                        <div className='row'>
                                {results}
                                {this.state.personId}
                                {this.state.person_results}
                        </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        results: state.movTv.results,
        person: state.movTv.personInfo
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPersonInfo })(SearchPage);
```

EDIT: Updated code for the component.

Comment: I'm not totally sure if it's the case here, but if you want to update the state every time props are received, you need https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops instead of componentDidMount and setState. Also, `pid = this.state.person_results.id ... this.setState({
                personId: pid,
            })` is an antipattern because state updates are async, `pid` refers to older state, always use updater function when setState derives from existing state, see https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate . Hope this helps somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Your variables `pid` and `person_results` are scoped to the module, ie they are defined "at the same level" as your `SearchPage` component. It is a good idea to only define `const`s at this level when using React (for example, your image url). Right now React can't listen to the changes of these variables and thus won't update the state at lines like this:

```
person_results = this.props.results[0].results[0];
pid = person_results.id;
```

If you want React to update the component upon variable change, you should instead define these variables as state properties inside the constructor:

```
class SearchPage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      person_results = /*...*/,
      pid: /*...*/
    }
  }

  /*...*/

}
```

and then refactor your code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You should move all of the logic you have in the `render` function up into the `componentDidMount`, but where you are returning `jsx` you will `setState` instead, so that your state represents what you want to render.  Then your `render` function should only have the `jsx`, which will render the data you have set in your state (in `componentDidMount`)

Side note, initially it seems weird that you would be calling `setState` after the component has 'mounted', but react will execute any `setState` calls in the `componentDidMount` before it actually renders

It will look something like -

```
class SearchPage extends React.Component {

    state = {
        personId: '',
        person_results: []
    }

        componentDidMount(){
            let pid;
            if (this.props.results.length > 0){
                if (this.props.results[0].results[0].media_type === 'person'){
                    person_results = this.props.results[0].results[0];
                    pid = person_results.id;
                } else if (this.props.results[0].results[1].media_type === 'person'){
                    person_results = this.props.results[0].results[1];
                    pid = person_results.id;
                } else if (this.props.results[0].results[2].media_type === 'person'){
                    person_results = this.props.results[0].results[2];
                    pid = person_results.id;
                }
            }
            this.setState({
                personId: pid,
                person_results
            })
        }


    render(){

            return (
                <div className='container-fluid'>
                        <div className='row'>
                                {this.state.personId}
                                {this.state.person_results}
                        </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        results: state.movTv.results,
        person: state.movTv.personInfo
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPersonInfo })(SearchPage);
```

it can be refactored more, but it'll give you an idea of where to start

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I tried this solution like you provided it. First it returned error with something about directly mutating state. Then I tried to use setState to change value of person_results into (this.props.results[0].results[0]) etc... But setting state doesn't even seem to work and when I tried to console.log (this.state.person_results) it always return empty array. I will update original post with the current state of the component.

Comment: Can I get any help with the above?